# How to use substring in create statement

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to use substr in hive create statement, but i couldnt able to create the table, can anyone help on this?

```
CREATE TABLE Contact(
RegionId varchar(6),
(substring(RegionID,1,2)) AS Channel 
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION'hdfs_location';
```

Comment: please explain 'couldn't make table' - was there an error?

Comment: this is the error i got "FAILED: ParseException line 51:0 cannot recognize input near '(' 'substr' '(' in column specification"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to use a UDF with a CREATE TABLE statement. This is because you are only defining a schema for the table, not performing operations on data. See this link for more details: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable

My suggestion is to define the column "Channel" as normal, e.g:

```
CREATE TABLE Contact(
RegionId varchar(6),
Channel string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION'hdfs_location';
```

And then when inserting data into the table, use the substring method:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE Contact 
SELECT RegionId, substring(RegionID,1,2) as Channel 
FROM table;
```